# Python telegram bot is failing with this error: "ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram-api, connection-reset

I made a telegram bot that continuously checks for new messages, and will send a message to a chat when a certain person sends a message. It is encountering this error, either some time after the program has been run, on start, or after a few loops through.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\eli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 790, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\eli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 491, in _make_request
    raise new_e
  File "C:\Users\eli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 467, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\eli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1096, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\eli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 642, in connect
    sock_and_verified = _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname(
  File "C:\Users\eli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 782, in _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname
    ssl_sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Users\eli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 470, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\eli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 514, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\eli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 501, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\eli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1041, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\eli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1310, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

This is the code:

```
import requests
import time
TOKEN = "************"
message = "********"
offset = 0
chat_id = "-**********"
while True:
    time.sleep(3)
    url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/getUpdates?offset={offset}"
    headers = {'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}
    results = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
    print(results)
    offset = str(results["result"][0].get("update_id"))
    if results["result"][0].get("message").get("from").get("First_name") == "*******":
        headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36'}
        url2 = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/sendMessage?chat_id={chat_id}&text={message}"
        print(requests.get(url2, headers=headers).json())
```

I tried to make it run continuously, limiting its request rate, and adding headers to my request call. I was expecting for this to run until manually stopped.

Comment: there are Python modules to work with telegram. Did you try to use them? Maybe they have to send something else to work correctly. OR maybe they have to get fresh `token` from time to time (it can be method to make it safer - and stop hackers).